# Executing make on the command line (Java)

Tags: java, command-line, makefile, executable

I'm aware that Makefiles and Java probably don't play nice together, but say you have something simple like this as a Makefile:

```
    JAVAC=javac
    sources = $(wildcard *.java)
    classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

    all: $(classes)

    clean :
        rm -f *.class

    %.class : %.java
        $(JAVAC) $<
```

I want to create an executable by typing something like:

```
    make myProgram
```

but I get a message saying:

```
    "make: *** No rule to make target `myProgram'.  Stop."
```

I know "make" by itself will work, but that's not what I want.

Is what I want to do even possible with a .java files?  If so, how can I modify the Makefile?  Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `myProgram` target, so make complains.

You could make `make myProgram` and `make` work and do the same thing by defining a `myProgram` target, and defining `all` to be `myProgram`:

```
all: myProgram

myProgram: $(classes)
```

Comment: after I execute make myProgram, say I want to do something like myProgram < input.txt > output.txt.  I get "myPogram: command not found".  Is there a way to do this without having to type java myProgram < input.txt > output.txt?

Comment: Depending on your environment, you can make a shell script or batch file that just calls `java myProgram`, then you can call the script or batch file.